# Site doesn't allow anonymous login but I want a public RSS feed

Tags: list, xml

I am trying to figure this one out.

My site is configured not to allow anonymous login.

That said, I want to provide an XML file of list items to be consumed by a public website on another server.

Thoughts? How would I best go about tackling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an anonymous sub directory (named 'RSS' for example) in IIS in the your web application directory. Then, you can create\update the xml here by using Timer job.

This way the url of your RSS still be of your web application

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom web service that has an operation that exposes the RSS feed. Inside the service operation you can use impersonation to read the data that populates the feed.

Answer (score 0):

Go through an intermediary either by pushing the xml content to a publicly accessible server that the other server can consume or extend the web application so it is publicly accessible and the web site can fetch it.

The push could done via a SSRS report saving the content as XML and pushing it to the public server or pulling it via Powershell and saving it to the public server.